# Cannot return data from intent sent by asynctask

Tags: android-intent, android-asynctask, null

It is my first class:

```
public class TessAsyncEngine extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

        private Activity acti;
        Context mContext;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
             //something here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(acti.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("mytext", s.toString());
            acti.startActivity(myIntent);
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
```

And second:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String resuiltString= bundle.getString("mytext");
```

String s is not null but resuiltString always return null. I try to change anyways but fail. Can you help me? Thank for watching.

Comment: You should write more information about why you are programing the async task.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code :

```
 String resuiltString = getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext");
```